# Bars in bar chart get smushed together

Tags: javascript, charts, cross-browser, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to make bar charts in d3, but my bars get smushed together when I look at them in Chrome. (They look fine in Firefox or Safari.)

For example, they look like this:

[image]

when there should really be some whitespace in between the bars.

Strangely, I see this even [in the official d3 tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html), but only on some of the bar charts -- the first and fourth bar charts on that page have the correct amount of spacing, but the second and third bar charts are smushed like the chart above.

What's the fix for this, so that bars display correctly in Chrome? What's special about the first and fourth bar charts on that page?

Comment: Are you using browser-based zoom? I'm unable to reproduce exactly although the spacing does disappear on some charts if I zoom out enough.

Comment: Confirmed - zooming out leads to "smushing". Hit `ctrl+0` in chrome to go to the default zoom level and see if the bars are still smushed.

Comment: Ah, d'oh, that was it, thanks! Didn't realize I was zoomed out :)

Comment: Great! Added as the "official" answer for others to find easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when using browser-based zoom, since a single pixel gap can collapse when zoomed out.

In Chrome, you need to select "View → Actual Size" or hit Ctrl/⌘-0 and this should fix it.